How to remove all tags after a given git commit?
Background: I have a private git repository. Now I wish to publish a part of the history up to a certain commit/date, so I need to remove all commits beyond that point and push the resulting git repository to GitHub.
For the main branch, I can simply reset it. But I'd like to also push the tags, so I need to keep the tags leading up to that commit but remove all later tags.

Thus the question - how can I remove all tags unrelated to the current commit, while keeping all the ancestor tags? Is there any way to do it efficiently instead of manually delete each tag?

@knittls's answer is a correct answer to your direct question. I would like to emphasize: if your intention is to actually push the limited history to a fresh new repository (which will be public), you just have to push that-point-in-time to  the new repo's main branch. The non-referenced commits will not be pushed.

git tag --contains "$commit" prints a list of all tags which contain the specified commit, i.e. "come after it". (git branch --contains "$commit" does the same for branches).
If you are scripting, git for-each-ref might be the better option. Fortunately, it supports the --contains option too. Use the format %(refname:short) to get the short name of each ref (tag or branch).
You can then use the output to delete these tags from the remote with a command such as git push origin :"$tagname" or git push --delete origin "$tagname". Use git tag -D and git branch -D to delete them locally, otherwise they could be pushed again with future pushes to the remote.
Note that unreachable commits are not pruned immediately and might still be reachable through GitHub links.

Thanks for the note. I forgot to mention that the original repository was not on GitHub, in another word I'm pushing to a brand new remote. I don't think any unreachable commits will be pushed in this case, right?

@zypA13510 if you removed all references to those commits, then they will not be pushed.
